# Summarizing Shared NumberVar

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am need to summarize two Shared NumberVar related fields in my main report. The sub-report is placed in Details A and the Shared NumberVar formula is placed in Details B.

What I am trying to achieve is a sum of the Shared NumberVar in the Group Footers #1, #2 and #3 and a sum of the below formula in the same group footers:

{@Castings to Make}*{PROD_Product.Nett_Weight}

Below are the respective Shared NumberVar formulas in the main and sub reports.

Main Report Formula:

Shared Numbervar CASTMAKE;

CASTMAKE

Sub Report Formula:

Shared Numbervar CASTMAKE;

CASTMAKE:=Sum ({WIP_Schedule.To_Do_Qty})

If you have any queries please don't hesitate to ask and I will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: thats fine... what isue you are facing in summarizing part.. you didn't post your problem

Comment: The issue is that I can't use insert summary and when I make a formula sum formula an error of "Field Cannot be summarized" shows up

Comment: You're only using a single shared variable?

Comment: Yes it is only a single shared variable from a sub-report. I am not sure it matters but the shared variable is of a summary in the subreport.

Comment: Your variable is changing values throughout the report; it doesn't make sense to perform a summary over a value that changes with every record... it can only be one value at a time.

Comment: I require all of the shared numbervariables in each record to sum in the group footer. is it possible? or is there a way around it?

Comment: sorted the problem out.